# SignalR - Can a Connection Belong to Multiple Groups at Once?

Tags: signalr

Can a connection be in multiple groups at once?   (ie, 'chatRoom51' and 'adminUsers')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A connection can belong to any number of groups simultaneously.